# Desktop icons keeps getting re-animated forever

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, desktop-icons, flicker, animations

I've recently updated Ubuntu to version 22.04.2. However, the desktop icons keeps re-animated forever. I tried to upgrade my system but it doesn't work. And the opening of files has become really slow. Can anyone please suggest a proper fix to this issue? 
Here is the link of the video of the issue:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w40_5TtdjV0AnPN-nZZV04pNrSelzcE6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Not normal behavior for sure. It looks as if the desktop icons extension crashes and is relaunched. Do you have any custom extensions installed (i.e., not systemwide installed but through e.g. Gnome Shell extensions website)? If yes, disable them all, restart the system and check if the issue persists.

Comment: I did as per you said. But the issue is still there.

Comment: When I try to end the GNOME shell process, the screen goes all black. It restarts the system when I enter Alt+Ctrl+Delete

Comment: Try also to temporarily create a new account then log in to that new account to see if the issue persists. If yes, then the problem may be related to your hardware, e.g. type of graphics card/driver, or even be related to a failing piece of hardware.